# How do I choose a specific position for ArcMap labels

Tags: arcmap, labeling, annotation

ArcMap 10.1: Labels on tiles I have set up for data driven pages randomly locate around the page instead of in the centre or in the corner where I want them to be despite allowing overlapping labels and setting labels weight to high. How do I choose a position for these labels pls?

Comment: Are these labels based on features, or based on the page/tile? I.e., do you want different titles for each page, or are there different features in each page that you want labeled?

Comment: @Baltok Labels are based on the tile of which there are circa. 100.  RyanDalton: Annotation class was created as per your suggestion but my annotation edit tool was greyed out in edit mode so I had no control over them. I am using ArcMap 10.1 Standard.

Answer (score 3):

For maximum control over the placement of labels, you will want to convert the labels to an [Annotation feature class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000m00000001000000.htm), which you can then specifically place in whatever location and orientation you choose.