# Change label position for a specific feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3

I try to change label position to specific feature. I red  [How do I choose a specific position for ArcMap labels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44369/how-do-i-choose-a-specific-position-for-arcmap-labels) , but i don't wont to convert the labels to annotation. Is it possible? I work with arcGIS 10.3

Answer (score 1):

Better to create database level annotation (not map level since map level moves when feature panned) and editing this like regular features. If you do not want this you can use SQL and select only specific feature using following way-

[image: demo]

N.B. You may need to adding same layer multiple times to label other feature (not that specific)

Comment: ok, how i proceed from here?

Comment: @newGIS what you meant?

Comment: when i go to sql quary- what i will write in there?

Comment: Ah! It is just regular sql what you use in select by attribute as in http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_Select_By_Attributes